# NanoHTTPD: Display images

Tags: java, nanohttpd

I'm trying to display an image on a browser using `NanoHTTPD server`, but always nothing to display.
This is a part of my serve method:

```
else if(uri.contains(".png")){
        SmallBinaryFiles smallBinaryFiles = new SmallBinaryFiles();
  InputStream is = new InputStream() {
            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };
  long i=0; 
  try {
//smallBinaryFiles.readSmallBinaryFiles(uri): converts binary file given by uri to byte[]
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(smallBinaryFiles.readSmallBinaryFile(uri));

  while ((is.read()) != -1){
      i++;
  }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HelloServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    return new NanoHTTPD.Response(NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, MIME_PNG, is,i);

    } 
 //declaration of MIME_PNG in NanoHTTPD Core
public static final String  MIME_PNG = "image/png";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while()` loop eats all of your input stream so there's nothing left to send. Put `-1` instead of `i` to make it a chunk response.

Besides, your `read()` method seems to throw an Exception when called. Use [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) instead.